# How to type texts with Android Keyboard using Appium and Python?

Tags: python, appium, ui-automation, appium-android

I am trying to develop a script in Python 3.7 using Appium in which I want to enter any text in the text fields using the keyboard opened by the app. Is there any way to type the text using keyboard without using send_keys method in appium.

I am also not sure how send_keys works internally, whether it only works when the app keyboard is opened or its just simply enters the text without keyboard opened.

I would prefer to type the text, character by character, using the keyboard of the smartphone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this is not a good idea because there is no way to touching keyboard keys as an element. I mean the appium cannot see the keyboard as elements. Also, you will need this if you only want to test the functionality of the keyboard itself. Otherwise technically `element.send_keys()` acts the same with no difference on `std-out`. Also, `element.set_text()` act the `paste` if you want.
Anyway, to reach this you should:

1- Open the keyboard by clicking on the input field

2- Find the coordinates of the keys and store them in a variable.

3- Touch the coordinates directly.